# how to transform a csv file to a structured XML file using XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I wanted to transform below CSV to XML

Example CSV Input

```
01,TeacherHeader1
02,StudentHeader1
03,SubjectHeader1
10,Grade1,Score99
10,Grade2,Score99
48,SubjectTrailer1
49,StudentTrailer1
02,StudentHeader2
03,SubjectHeader1
10,Grade1,Score50
10,Grade2,Score50
48,SubjectTrailer1
49,StudentTrailer2
50,TeacherTrailer1
```

Output should be

```
  <FileHeader> 
    <id>01</id>  
    <name>TeacherHeader1</name> 
  </FileHeader>  
  <GroupRecord> 
    <GroupHeader> 
      <id>02</id>  
      <name>StudentHeader1</name> 
    </GroupHeader>  
    <AccountRecord> 
      <AccountHeader> 
        <id>03</id>  
        <name>SubjectHeader1</name> 
      </AccountHeader>  
      <AccountDetails> 
        <Details> 
          <id>10</id>  
          <name>Grade1</name>  
          <value>Score99</value> 
        </Details>  
        <Details> 
          <id>10</id>  
          <name>Grade2</name>  
          <value>Score99</value> 
        </Details> 
      </AccountDetails>  
      <AccountTrailer> 
        <id>48</id>  
        <name>SubjectTrailer1</name> 
      </AccountTrailer> 
    </AccountRecord>  
    <GroupTrailer> 
      <id>49</id>  
      <name>StudentTrailer1</name> 
    </GroupTrailer> 
  </GroupRecord>  
  <GroupRecord> 
    <GroupHeader> 
      <id>02</id>  
      <name>StudentHeader2</name> 
    </GroupHeader>  
    <AccountRecord> 
      <AccountHeader> 
        <id>03</id>  
        <name>SubjectHeader1</name> 
      </AccountHeader>  
      <AccountDetails> 
        <Details> 
          <id>10</id>  
          <name>Grade1</name>  
          <value>Score99</value> 
        </Details>  
        <Details> 
          <id>10</id>  
          <name>Grade2</name>  
          <value>Score99</value> 
        </Details> 
      </AccountDetails>  
      <AccountTrailer> 
        <id>48</id>  
        <name>SubjectTrailer1</name> 
      </AccountTrailer> 
    </AccountRecord>  
    <GroupTrailer> 
      <id>49</id>  
      <name>StudentTrailer2</name> 
    </GroupTrailer> 
  </GroupRecord>  
  <FileTrailer> 
    <id>50</id>  
    <name>TeacherTrailer1</name> 
  </FileTrailer>
```

where

```
01 = FileHeader 
02 = GroupHeader (grouped inside GroupRecord)
03 = AccountHeader (grouped inside AccountRecord)
10 = Details (grouped inside AccountDetails)
48 = AccountTrailer (grouped inside AccountRecord)
49 = GroupTrailer (group inside GroupRecord)
50 = FileTrailer
```

I wanted to transform the CSV above into a properly structured XML as seen above.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Using `unparsed-text(-lines)` plus `tokenize` you should be able to transform the text into XML. Then you can use normal `xsl:for-each-group`. I am not sure which approach exactly you need, your wanted output due to its formatting seems to indicate soem nesting which the XML does not show, you might want to improve the formatting and remove any indentation where the XML is not supposed to nest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did add some legend below my post to point out what the tags are for each record identifier (which is the first two characters per line on the CSV) and also point out where it should be placed or grouped. You can properly format it by copying the XML and using an external editor.

Comment: Hope somebody can help me asap :(

Comment: The CSV has `Score99` and `Score50`, why does the output as XML only have `Score99`?

Comment: My Bad - that was a typo from copy-pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you can process the text file with `unparsed-text` and `tokenize` to convert it to XML (or use `unparsed-text-lines` and `tokenize` in XSLT 3 if available), then the rest of the tasks can be done with nested `xsl:for-each-group`s, perhaps even with one or two recursive functions once there has been a regular pattern established; the following tries to spell out the nested `for-each-group`s:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expand-text="yes"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="data" as="xs:string">01,TeacherHeader1
02,StudentHeader1
03,SubjectHeader1
10,Grade1,Score99
10,Grade2,Score99
48,SubjectTrailer1
49,StudentTrailer1
02,StudentHeader2
03,SubjectHeader1
10,Grade1,Score50
10,Grade2,Score50
48,SubjectTrailer1
49,StudentTrailer2
50,TeacherTrailer1</xsl:param>

<xsl:param name="header-ids" as="xs:string*"
  select="'01', '02', '03', '10', '48', '49', '50'"/>

<xsl:param name="header-names" as="xs:string*"
  select="'FileHeader ', 'GroupHeader', 'AccountHeader', 'Details', 'AccountTrailer', 'GroupTrailer', 'FileTrailer'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="lines">
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($data, '\r?\n')">
          <line>
              <xsl:variable name="tokens" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(., ',')"/>
              <id>{$tokens[1]}</id>
              <name>{$tokens[2]}</name>
              <xsl:if test="$tokens[3]">
                  <value>{$tokens[3]}</value>
              </xsl:if>
          </line>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$lines/line" group-starting-with="line[id = '01']">
          <File>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
              <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-ending-with="line[id = '50']">
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[position() lt last()]" group-starting-with="line[id = '02']">
                      <GroupRecord>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-ending-with="line[id = '49']">
                              <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[position() lt last()]" group-starting-with="line[id = '03']">
                                  <AccountRecord>
                                      <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                                      <AccountDetails>
                                          <xsl:apply-templates select="(current-group() except .)[id != '48']"/>
                                      </AccountDetails>
                                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[id = '48']"/>
                                  </AccountRecord>
                              </xsl:for-each-group>
                              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()]"/>
                          </xsl:for-each-group>
                      </GroupRecord>
                  </xsl:for-each-group>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()]"/>
              </xsl:for-each-group>
          </File>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="line">
      <xsl:element name="{$header-names[index-of($header-ids, current()/id)]}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEaSv8. The sample data has been inlined for completeness and compactness of the example but you could of course use `<xsl:param name="data" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text('file.txt')"/>` instead. I also used the `xsl:mode` declaration and the `name="xsl:initial-template"`, both XSLT 3 features which you would need to adapt for an XSLT 2 processor to spell out the identity transformation and to use a different template name like e.g. `name="main"` as the entry point for the code. I also used text values template like `<id>{$tokens[1]}</id>` there, for an XSLT 2 processor you would need to use e.g. `<id><xsl:value-of select="$tokens[1]"/</id>`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I had to remove all funtions that is not supported for XSLT 2 
For name="xsl:initial-template"
I don't have to replicate this since we have a standard back-end solution that converts CSV to XML which is a basic one. So, the actual input for this XSL is a simple XML with each element containing each line from CSV (eg: <data><record><field1>01,TeacherHeader1</field1></record></data>
For xsl:mode, I haven't thought yet on how to convert this for XSLT 2
But this solution pretty much solve my problem regarding grouping technique (with header/trailer)
Truly appreciate your effort